# how to add class to <?php if ( get_field('cast') )

Tags: php, class

I am using this code and I want to open field in cast class but I cant...

```
<?php if ( get_field('cast') ) {
    echo '<div class="cast">
              <h4 class="title">casts</h4>
              </br>
              ' . the_field ('cast') . '
          </div>'
;}?>
```

but my html source this :(

```
<?php the_field('cast')?>
<div class"cast">
    <h4></h4>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

I want open the acf field inside the class cast , But the acf field before class called , sorry i can not good speack english

Comment: What do you exactly want.Please edit your quetion

Comment: Your questions includes function of acf(advanced custom field for wordpress) , you have to show the complete code of above code you are trying to work with , else we can't help you .

Comment: this link not open for me advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field please help me how to fix this :(

Comment: @alam7o  copy and paste your file's code into question , we can't help you , without looking at what is above the code you have posted. and the link : [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) is opening for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, but i fixed with this code

```
<?php if( get_field('cast') ): ?>
       <div class="cast">
           <h4 class="title">cast</h4>
           <?php the_field('cast'); ?>
       </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope so help for other user